# Combine different events of different selectors to one function

Tags: jquery, events, css-selectors

How do I combine $('#foo').click() and $('#bar').change() in one and same function? #bar may not be triggered by click, and #foo not by change.

So hypothetically:

```
$('#foo').click() + $('#bar').change() (function{
  //...
});
```

This is **not** what I am looking for:

```
function foobar() {
  // ...
}
$('#foo').click(function{
  foobar();
});
$('#bar').change(function{
  foobar();
});
```

Associated HTML:

```
<select id="bar">
  <option>dummy1</option>
  <option>dummy2</option>
</select>
<button id="foo">foo</button>
```

Comment: Please show the associated HTML.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy no need for the HTML in this question

Comment: You can't join two selectors and two events like that, just do it the way you're doing it !

Comment: And the reason you don't want to use the jQuery example in your code is what?

Comment: I would prefer one group of code rather than separates and was looking for the right way to do it. Seem there is no righter way.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5vgKm/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really the only way if you don't want `click` on `#bar` or `change` on `#foo`:

```
$( '#foo, #bar' ).on( 'click change',  function ( event ) {
    if( ( event.type == 'click' && event.target.id == 'foo' )
        || ( event.type == 'change' && event.target.id == 'bar' ) ) {

        //process event here
    };
} );
```

Though I think the method you listed as **not** wanting is the better way to do it. Which is easier to read and understand?:

```
function foobar() {
    // ...
};

$( '#foo' ).click( foobar );
$( '#bar' ).change( foobar );
```

Comment: Thanks for sorting this out.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(":input").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
    foobar(); //you can pass here the id as parameter to your function
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5vgKm/

Comment: OP mentioned he doesn't want to do this way.